# App behaviour changes after disconnected from xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am developing a new release of my app and have come across a very frustrating issue. i have some code that repositions a view on the screen after rotation(see below code) When i run it in the simulator there are no issues, when i test on a physical device there is also no issue, until i disconnect from xCode. After disconnecting from Xcode the view no longer re locates correctly. If i reconnect to Xcode and run again it still won't work as it used to/expected. I added the logging you see in the code and now know that on first execution the heigh and with are logging correctly but after disconnect they are reversed. I have also installed an adhoc distribution to a two different devices and again on first execution everything works fine(no Xcode connection this time). But if i completely close the app (double tap home and wipe up) on the next execution we get exactly the same outcome as before with the view repositioning off the screen(presumably the NSlog values will again be reversed). I have searched high and low and can't find any solutions at all.

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)note
{
NSLog(@"rotate");
int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
int width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
NSLog(@"%@,%d",@"height: ",height);
NSLog(@"%@,%d",@"width: ",width);

UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)==YES){

    if ([self.vcID.text isEqualToString:@"i4"]) {
        self.addheightCont.constant = 50;

    }else{
        self.addheightCont.constant = 100.0;

    }

}else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)==YES){

    if ([self.vcID.text isEqualToString:@"i5"]) {
        self.addheightCont.constant = 32.0;

    }else if ([self.vcID.text isEqualToString:@"i4"]) {
        self.addheightCont.constant = 32.0;

    }else{
        self.addheightCont.constant = 50.0;
    }

}


if (height==568) {

    self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
    [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

    self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 284)];
        [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 445)];
        [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 445)];
    }

    if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 284)];
    }
}else if (height==480){

        self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

        self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
        [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

        self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

        if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
            [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
            [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 445)];
            [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 445)];
        }

        if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
            [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 284)];
        }



}else if ((height==320) && (width==568)){

    self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
    [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

    self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
    self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(277, 160)];
        [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 304)];
        [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 304)];

    }
    if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(284, 160)];
    }
}else if ((height==320) && (width==480)){
    self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
    [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

    self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(240, 160)];
        [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 304)];
        [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 304)];

    }
    if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(284, 160)];
    }
}else if ((height==375) && (width==667)){
    self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
    [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

    self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 667, 375);
    self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 667, 375);
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(333.5, 187.5)];
        [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 304)];
        [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 304)];

    }
    if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(333.5, 115)];
    }
}else if (height==667) {

    self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
    [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

    self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667);
    self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667);
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(187.5, 333.5)];
        [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 445)];
        [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 445)];
    }

    if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(187.5,115)];
    }
}else if (height==736) {

    self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
    [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

    self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 736);
    self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 736);
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(207, 333.5)];
        [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 514)];
        [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 514)];
    }

    if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(207,115)];
    }
}else if (height==414){
    self.imageScroller.delegate = self;

    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 0.0;
    [self.imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

    self.LargeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 736, 414);
    self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 736, 414);
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    if (self.CommentsView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.CommentsView setCenter:CGPointMake(368, 187.5)];
        [self.ShowCommentsButton setCenter:CGPointMake(24, 380)];
        [self.LikeButtonbutton setCenter:CGPointMake(70.5, 380)];

    }
    if (self.editCommentView.alpha == 1.0) {
        [self.editCommentView setCenter:CGPointMake(368, 115)];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Damn, This much code?

Comment: sorry for the long code but i didn't want to miss anything.

Comment: honestly, what you are doing is totally wrong... You should consider using auto-layout...

Comment: I did try auto layout but i am animating the view onto the screen from below by changing the location. I tried layout changing the constrains in the animation block but although it placed the view correctly it didn't animate on to the screen it just appeared in the final position. I then tried to just change the constraint after the animation was complete but that resulted in unexpected changes to the size of the view. thats why i went to manually locating it. if i knew how to animate the view onto the screen from below i would would as that would wipe out all that code for the rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Fahim's suggestion i did some research on auto layout and as a result have managed to implement a fix using auto layout. I have set a constraint for the distance of the comment view from the top and sides of the top of the parent view and simply change the constant values using the code below to animate the view on and off the screen. As a result i no longer need any of the code in my question in the view rotation. Although i didn't find an answer to why the behaviour changes when the phone is disconnected from Xcode its no longer an issue with auto layout doing all the work.

To animate the view on screen i use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

                self.CommentViewOffset.constant = 40;
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
```

And off the screen i use:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

  if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)==YES){
     self.CommentViewOffset.constant = 750.0;
     self.editComentViewOffset.constant = 750;
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

  }else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)==YES){
     self.CommentViewOffset.constant = 440;
     self.editComentViewOffset.constant = 440;
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
     }
```

Now i have no need to do anything in the deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification method as everything is handled with auto layout. I must say i have avoided auto layout completely until now and really wish i had taken the time to do the research earlier.